# Get the last three months dynamically

Tags: mdx

I have the following MDX query

```
SELECT 
  Hierarchize
  (
    {
      [PERIOD].[Year Month].&[2014 / 10]
     ,[PERIOD].[Year Month].&[2014 / 11]
     ,[PERIOD].[Year Month].&[2014 / 12]
    }
  ) ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Measures].[Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Total Cost]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Asset];
```

Is there a way to get the last three months dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as George says except in your context I don't think you need `EXISTING`:

```
SELECT 
  Hierarchize
  (
    Tail([PERIOD].[Year Month].members,3)
  ) ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    [Measures].[Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Total Cost]
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Asset];
```

Answer (score 1):

Last N values from any axis could be retrieved by using `Tail` [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146056.aspx):

```
Tail(EXISTING [PERIOD].[Year Month],3)
```

Retrieves a set of last 3 items of `Month` level for `Period` dimension